# how to show an indicator in activity if notification comes and user clear all notification from notification tray in android

Tags: android, notifications

I have an Activity in which I have a tab bar , each tab opens a different fragment. What I want to do is if a notification comes and app is in background and user does not click on notification but directly opens the app, at that time I want to show an indicator on the tab for which the notification has been like whatsapp and instagram shows it.
I am able to do it when that activity is opened by sending a broadcast from notification service class and receiving it in that activity, but if app is closed that time my broadcast logic doesn't work if user directly enter the app instead of clicking on notification, and I am not able to detect for which tab that notification is sent.
So is there any other logic with which I can done that task.
Thanks in advance.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.ottice.ottice.AppController;
import com.ottice.ottice.DashboardActivity;
import com.ottice.ottice.utils.Common;
import com.ottice.ottice.utils.NotificationUtils;
import com.ottice.ottice.utils.PrefrencesClass;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Map;

/**
* TODO: Add a class header comment!
*/

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG =        MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
private Intent resultIntent;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Map<String, String> message = remoteMessage.getData();
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(message);
            Log.e("TITLE",""+json);
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {
    super.onDeletedMessages();
}



private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {

        if(AppController.currentFragment != null){
            Log.e("CURRENT   FRAGMENT",""+AppController.currentFragment.get().getClass().getSimpleName());
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Common.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new    NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }
    }
}



private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject data) {

    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
    resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

    try {
        String title = data.getString("time");
        String message = data.getString("message");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);


        resultIntent.putExtra("message", data.toString());
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext()))    {
            if(AppController.isDashboardActivityActive) {
                if (AppController.currentFragment != null) {
                    // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                    Intent pushNotification = new   Intent(Common.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                } else {
                    Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Common.NOTIFICATION_DATA_RECEIVER);
                       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                    // play notification sound
                    notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
                }
            }else {
                notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, resultIntent, null);
                // play notification sound
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

            }
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, resultIntent, null);
            // play notification sound
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @RobWilkins  I have added my FCM service class code where I am handling the notification you can take a look on it.